# How to create latest posts feed based on user's subscriptions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, nosql

I need to implement latest posts page in my mobile app that uses firebase real-time database.

System description:

Application users (AU) can subscribe to content creators (CC) who create posts. For instance, we have a user AU123 who subscribes to content creators CC1, CC2, CC3. Another user AU456 subscribes CC2, CC6, CC7 What is the most optimal way to perform operation getLatestPosts(AU123)?

In general, it is a very similar functionality that Facebook offers (but way simplified as we only rely on the post creation date to construct the latest list). We have users that follow (subscribe) other users (Content creators). When we open up Facebook, we can see a list of latest posts.

A simple solution would be to simply create "latest" list for each of the users and once CC posts, he also appends a reference to his post to that list. But having 1000 users subscribing to a CC, we would need to append that postID to 1000 lists.

Another approach could be to store all references to the posts in a list along with the timestamp. Then, each user could fetch that list and pick only the posts from CC that his subscribing. This solution is not optimal either as the posts list can quickly get very long and finding even a single post belonging to the subscribed CC can take a while (assuming we have 1000 CC that create 1 post per day and user that subscribes only to few of them).

Do you have any articles or ideas how to approach this problem? Is is even possible to solve in a reasonable way using only firebase database?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already have two valid approaches, and are making the right considerations. Both duplicating on write, and client-side joining on read are common and valid.

Most systems that do this at scale, do a hybrid of these two approaches, deciding whether to duplicate or join based on the number of subscribers of the content creator.

One thing I'd like to dispel is that lookups are slow. Many developers new to Firebase think so, but it is seldom the case as [Firebase can pipeline most of these requests over its existing web socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: That's a surprising answer, I hoped there's a better way :)
Regardless, the first solution is pretty straight forward as we have already filtered information for the user and we can simply fetch the list of latest posts from his node. Regarding the second option, do you know a way to fetch only keys relevant to user? We have a node latest with CC1: timestamp, CC2: timestamp etc. can we make a batch request to retrieve only CC1, CC2, CC3 (in case of AU123)? It would be a waste to fetch the whole latest node and filter it out on the frontend side. Maybe Cloud Firestore is a better suit here?

Comment: There's no way to get posts for a bunch of creators, so you'd have to have another loop. The code can get a bit much, which is why you're considering modeling a user's feed in the database: that was the code to read it simple, although writes are more complex. Cloud Firestore allows `WHERE IN` type queries with up to 10 values, but I think that limit of 10 is not enough for your model, because it'd mean you could only follow 10 creators before you'd also have to perform multiple queries and were back to the same code you seem to want to avoid.